# Facebook post via url

Tags: facebook, share

I am trying to send this to facebook and it works except for the title "Some Page Title" is not showing up in the post. [Example](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F%3Fq%3Dbla&amp%3Bt=Some+Page+Title)

The format i am using:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<url>&t=<page title>
```

Is passing title not supported any more?

TIA

Comment: That format doesn't work anymore you have to provide `Open Graph` meta tags, or use feed method to change title ..

Comment: Thanks Adam. Can you please point me to more information relating to "use feed method".

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite `Open Graph` meta tags you're only chance is with `feed` method which requires an app id

JS

```
$('#facebook-share').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    FB.ui({

        method: 'feed', // feed method! 
        name: 'My title', // overwrites "og:title"
        link: 'https://www.facebook.com/Retrogram', // required param
        picture: 'http://i.imgur.com/SKwsQM2.png?1', // overwrites "og:image"
        caption: 'My caption', // overwrite caption
        description: 'My description' // overwrites "og:description"

    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdamAzad/Y85jX/)